# Rails 4 - How to send newsletter-like emails with delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, delayed-job

I want to send a summary of our new lists to our users every morning. What's the best approach to do that with Ruby On Rails 4, ActiveRecord (using SendGrid) and Delayed Job?

I am currently doing it this way:

In controller:

```
def yesterday_listings_for_users
    yesterday_listings = Listings.where('status = "0" AND (DATE(created_at) = ?)', Date.today - 1)
    if yesterday_listings.count > 0
      NotificationMailer.delay.yesterday_listings_for_users_notification
    end  
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

And then in the mailer:

```
  def yesterday_listings_for_users_notification
    @listings = Listing.where('status = "0" AND (DATE(created_at) = ?)', Date.today-1)

    mail(to: 'myemail@gmail.com', subject: "Latest Listings", from: 'no-reply@mywebsite.com')            
  end
```

With using a CRON job, this sends me the report every morning on my email address. I have a few hundreds of users in the database and I would like to send them this email as well.

How to do that? I am wondering about something like this:

```
  def yesterday_listings_for_users_notification
    @listings = Listing.where('status = "0" AND (DATE(created_at) = ?)', Date.today-1)
    Users.all.each do |user|
      mail(to: user.email, subject: "Latest Listings", from: 'no-reply@mywebsite.com')          
    end
  end
```

However, is looping through hundreds of records in database and sending hundreds of emails in a delayed mailer method recommened (or appropriate)?

Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually prefer to use `Sidekiq` along with [`Sidetiq`](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) but if you want to use `delayed_job` I would advice you to use the [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem for simplicity.

> Whenever is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and
>   deploying cron jobs.

1. Add `gem 'whenever'` to your gemfile
2. run the command `wheneverize .` which will generate a file `config/schedule.rb`
3. In your `config/schedule.rb` do the following.

   ```
   every 1.day, :at => '11:30 am' do
     runner "User.delay.send_daily_newsletter"
   end
   ```
4. In your `user.rb` define the method `send_daily_newsletter` and use `find_each` instead of `all.each` (batches)

   ```
   def self.send_daily_newsletter
     listings = Listing.where('status = "0" AND (DATE(created_at) = ?)', Date.today - 1).select(:title).to_json
     User.select(:id, :email).find_each do |u|
       NotificationMailer.delay.send_daily_newsletter(u.email, listings)
     end
    end
   ```
5. In your `notification_mailer.rb` define `send_daily_newletter`

   ```
   def send_daily_newsletter(user_email, listings)
     @listings = listings
     mail(to: user_email, subject: "Latest Listings", from: 'no-reply@mywebsite.com')
   end
   ```

This way you will have one delayed job to get all users and send each email using a separate worker which is the most optimal way to do this task.

> Note: Do not forget to change the methods for listings in your view
>   from, for example, `listing.title` to `listing[:title]` since we are
>   passing the listings as `json`.
>
> If you do not want to pass them as `json` every time to every delayed
>   task just cache the listings in [`Rails.cache`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1?autoplay=true) and clear it
>   after you finish sending.

**EDIT:**

If you would like to use the cache method since you ran into a problem in the `delayed_job` gem, edit your `send_daily_newsletter` method in your mailer. (That's is why I would go to redis-based `Sidekiq` rather than mysql-based `delayed_job`.

```
    def send_daily_newsletter(user_email)
      @listings = Rails.cache.fetch('today_listings') { Listing.where('status = "0" AND (DATE(created_at) = ?)', Date.today - 1) }
      mail(to: user_email, subject: "Latest Listings", from: 'no-reply@mywebsite.com')
    end
```

and in your `user.rb`

```
     def self.send_daily_newsletter
      User.select(:id, :email).find_each do |u|
        NotificationMailer.delay.send_daily_newsletter(u.email)
      end
      Rails.cache.clear('today_listings')
     end
```

Good luck. I have been doing these email newsletters for a while now and they are truly pain :D

Comment: I hope it provides the solution to your problem

Comment: The problem seems to be that I cannot put an object (listings) to the delayed_job MySQL table - because I get this error: **Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'handler' at row 1**

Comment: I have edited the answer to avoid passing the listings each time to the `delayed_job`

Comment: Thank you Mohamed. I am trying to make it work, but **Rails.cache.fetch** is still empty (though the ActiveRecord return rows - it looks it cannot save anything into **Rails.cache.fetch**.